# Can you do a mysqli select query to get all rows with a time stamp from x to x

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database setup where there are three columns:

- name
- email
- timestamp (standard Unix timestamp)

What I would like to do is to select all rows between two timestamps.

Example:

```
+-------+---------+------+
| name  | email   | time |
+-------+---------+------+
| dave  | mymail  | 1234 |
| john  | hismail | 1235 |
| jim   | mail    | 1236 |
| liam  | mail1   | 1237 |
| colin | mail2   | 1238 |
+-------+---------+------+
```

I would like to select all rows between 1235 to 1237 (all rows in between) - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `name`, `email`, `time` FROM `table` WHERE `time` >= 1235 AND `time` <= 1237
```

Answer (score 1):

[BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)  operator will help you

```
SELECT `name`, `email`, `time` FROM `table` WHERE `time` BETWEEN 1235 AND 1237;
```